# Ceilometer Http 500

Tags: openstack

I was installing Ceilometer using this guide: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/ceilometer/install/manual.html

After I have finished everything, I try to test it by using: ceilometer meter-list and it gives me this error: `HTTPInternalServerError (HTTP 500)`

Here's what I have in the log:

```
root@iaas-hk01:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# tail -f /var/log/apache2/ceilometer_error.log
[Wed Jul 24 18:35:48 2013] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 80, in connect
[Wed Jul 24 18:35:48 2013] [error]     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
[Wed Jul 24 18:35:48 2013] [error] 
[Wed Jul 24 18:35:48 2013] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 281, in connect
[Wed Jul 24 18:35:48 2013] [error]     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
[Wed Jul 24 18:35:48 2013] [error] 
[Wed Jul 24 18:35:48 2013] [error] OperationalError: (OperationalError) unable to open database file None None
[Wed Jul 24 18:35:48 2013] [error] 
[Wed Jul 24 18:35:48 2013] [error] [client 192.168.10.16] mod_wsgi (pid=2178): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/api/app.wsgi'.
[Wed Jul 24 18:35:48 2013] [error] [client 192.168.10.16] TypeError: expected byte string object for header value, value of type int found
```

Hopefully someone can provide me some guidance in fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

you should set the keystone api - end points. so that ceilometer api can talk with keystone...

Here are steps...

```
Create a service for ceilometer in keystone

$ keystone service-create --name=ceilometer \
                      --type=metering \
                      --description="Ceilometer Service"
Create an endpoint in keystone for ceilometer

$ keystone endpoint-create --region RegionOne \
                       --service_id $CEILOMETER_SERVICE \
                       --publicurl "http://$SERVICE_HOST:8777/" \
                       --adminurl "http://$SERVICE_HOST:8777/" \
                       --internalurl "http://$SERVICE_HOST:8777/"
```

Note that: 8777 is the default port of ceilometer if you have customised use the customised one..